# uWSGI workers stuck: why

Tags: python, multithreading, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi version 2.0.13.1 with the following config:

```
bin/uwsgi  -M -p 5 -C -A 4 -m -b 8192 -s :3031 --wsgi-file bin/django.wsgi --pidfile var/run/uwsgi.pid --touch-reload=var/run/reload-uwsgi.touch --max-requests=1000 --reload-on-rss=450 --py-tracebacker var/run/pytrace --auto-procname --stats 127.0.0.1:3040 --threads 40 --reload-mercy 600 --listen 200
```

(absolute path names cut)

When I run `uwsgitop`, all 5 workers appear as busy. When I try to get the stack trace for each worker / thread, using the py-tracebacker, I get no answer. The processes just hang.

How could I research what exact fact is what makes uwsgi processes hang?

How could I prevent this situation?

I know the harakiri parameter but I'm not sure if the process is killed if it has other active threads.

PD: "reload mercy" is set to a very high value avoid the killing of workers with still active threads (seems to be a bug). We have some Web requests which still take a long long time (which are in the way to be converted to jobs).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get the solution for it?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1599. Basically, the import of some stdlib modules like logging may not be thread safe in Python 2.7. So I moved the imports to the wsgi module itself, which are run before uwsgi forks the workers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I added already a comment, here goes a longer description.

Warning: the problem only arose when using more than one worker process AND more than one thread (-p --threads).

Short version: In Python 2.7.x some modules are not 100% thread safe during imports (logging, implicit imports of codecs). Try to import all of such problematic modules in the wsgi file given to uwsgi (i.e, before uwsgi forks).

Long version: In https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1599 I analysed the problem and found that it could be related to [python bug with the logging module](https://bugs.python.org/issue6721). The problem can be solved importing and initializing any critical modules BEFORE uwsgi forks which happens after the wsgi script given to uwsgi is executed.

I finally resolved my problem importing the django settings.ROOT_URLCONF directly or indirectly from the wsgi file. This also has the benefits of reducing memory consumption (because the code base shared between workers is much bigger) and per-worker initialization time.